# Must link to dependent libraries' dependents; why?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I have an application - let's call it "P" - that uses custom SO's: A.so, B.so, and C.so
The A.so library uses another custom library - D.so - as well as SSL and the math library.
The "P" application makes no calls whatsoever to SSL or math routines.

On macOS (with clang), I could build P with `-lA -lB -lC` and all was good.
I'm migrating everything to Linux (Debian) with GCC.
Now, when I bulid P, I have to `-lA -lB -lC -lD -lm -lssl`

What am I doing wrong?
I'm using simple makefiles - no autoconfig, no cmake, etc.
Could this be an "install_name_tool" vs. "chrpath" issue when I build the libraries?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of a combination of the following two factors:

1. On macOS, the standard C library (`libSystem.dylib`) which is automatically linked by the compiler already includes a lot more functionality than on Linux. It may include some (or *all*) the necessary functions for your program. For example, as you can read from [this documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/intro.3.html), `libSystem` already includes the math library (which is a separate file on Linux and needs to be linked with `-lm`).
2. The shared libraries you are linking were compiled for macOS with additional functions already embedded into them, so those don't need to link to other shared libraries. It is not uncommon for a library to depend on different other libraries on different operating systems.

On the other hand, on Linux, the standard C library is split into different files: `-lc` is automatically linked by the compiler, but the math library (`-lm`) and other parts (`-ldl`, `-lpthread`, etc) are not, and therefore need to be linked manually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Understood ... but for a simpler example ... If I have a program, P, that uses my shared library, A, and my shared library A uses pthreads, only A needs to be linked against pthreads. When I build P ,I should only need to link it against A.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Turns out that `clang` - regardless of development platform - is a lot more forgiving with the order of parameters and options when linking. With `clang`, you can pretty much put your `-I`, `-L`, `-l`, other options and object files in whatever order you want. Not so with `gcc`; it's much more particular. `clang` made me lazy.